# How do I concurrently increment a page view count using linq-to-sql?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, architecture, concurrency

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application using Linq-to-SQL for my data access layer. I'm trying to increment a Views field every time the Details action is called, but I'm receiving a "Row not found or changed" error on db.SubmitChanges() if two people happen to hit the action at the same time.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();

    var idea = db.Ideas.Where(i => i.IdeaPK == id).Single();

    idea.Views++;

    db.SubmitChanges();

    return View(new IdeaViewModel(idea));
}
```

I could set the UpdateCheck of the Views field to "Never" in my .dbml (Data Model), which would get rid of the error, but then the idea record could be updated twice with the same Views count. i.e.

```
First instance of Details action gets idea record with Views count of 1.
Second instance of Details action gets idea record with Views count of 1.
First instance increments Views to 2
First instance commits
Second instance increments Views to 2
Second instance commits

Result: Views field is 2 
Expected Result: Views field should be 3
```

I looked into using a TransactionScope, but I got the following deadlock error from one of the two calls:

> Transaction (Process ID 54) was
>   deadlocked on lock resources with
>   another process and has been chosen as
>   the deadlock victim. Rerun the
>   transaction.

when I updated my action to look like:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();

    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope()){
        var idea = db.Ideas.Where(i => i.IdeaPK == id).Single();

        idea.Views++;

        db.SubmitChanges();

        return View(new IdeaViewModel(idea));
    }
}
```

I also tried increasing the TransactionScope timeout using the TransactionScopeOptions and that didn't seem to help (but I may have to set it elsewhere as well). I could probably solve this example by doing the increment in a single SQL command using db.ExecuteQuery, but I was trying to figure out how to make this work so I'll know what to do in more complex scenarios (where I want to execute multiple commands in a single transaction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not need transactions or stored procedures.  Just use `DataContext.ExecuteCommand`:

```
db.ExecuteCommand("UPDATE Ideas SET Views = Views + 1 WHERE IdeaPK = {0}", id);
```

This will execute it as one SQL statement, and is thus atomic.

Comment: That's what I've done for now, but I've got another situation that is more complex and that I can't accomplish in a single database call. I was hoping that using TransactionScope around my read and update would put a lock on that row until the transaction commits, which would solve the problem, but I can't seem to get TransactionScope to put a lock on that row.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should make a stored procedure which will atomically increment the field you want and call it through LINQ2SQL.

Other option is to wrap your operation into a transaction with appropriate isolation level.

Comment: What is the appropriate isolation level? I think in this case it would be Serializable, but that resulted in a deadlock when I tried it.

Comment: If understand it correctly, with two separate statements it can end in a deadlock. So you should place read and write really close to each other to reduce the chance of deadlock (create another context, read the row, increment it and write it back). Also, AFAIK, it's a different story with a single `UPDATE` statement (of the form `UPDATE SET field=field+1 ...`). I'll post an update when my DBA friend answers.

Comment: I've asked him and done some research and it seems you really need to make an SP with a single `UPDATE` which will work even with `READ COMMITTED`. Two separate operations within a transaction with an isolation level ensuring proper increment will likely cause a deadlock. You can refer for Rick answer for an example of such SP.

Comment: @xelibrion, test what? Stored procedures can be represented as 'methods' in LINQ2SQL so you can test it as anything else. As for reproducing the issue with 2 separate statements it's enough to simulate it in Management Studio by separation `SELECT` and `UPDATE` with `WAITFOR DELAY`... I don't get your question, to be honest.

Comment: Usage of stored procedures leads to untestable and eventually unmaintainable code. This approach spreads logic between application level and persistence level and it ends up with system where no one is responsible for anything

Comment: I mean, how will you perform unit testing on stored procedures without having dependency to real database (in memory)?

Comment: @xelibrion, you can't do everything through ORM. Sometimes one has to rely on SPs. Also, with small projects it might be easier to maintain a couple of SPs than to add a whole new layer just for two or three operations. Also, properly wrapped, SPs are mockable, testable etc. Even replaceable seamlesly by something else. I agree that using SPs introduces several problems, but SPs are not universal evil and one shouldn't try to avoid them at all costs.

Comment: @xelibrion I'll test it against a real database. After all, SP is a part of database. How will you test that your ORM is working properly without a database? (I mean there are some things after all that can be tested only with a real DB and people live with it somehow) Also, you do not need to use an SP directly in you code. Wrap it in a service of sorts that calls it...

Comment: Sure I can. Using SPs is a naive option, which is used when you don't have more elegant and robust architecture solution. I use in-memory database for testing purpose

Comment: @xelibrion, I strongly beleive that there are scenarios when SP is a less evil and also when using SPs is the best choice. For instance, if you have to execute some highly optimized SQL script it's better to wrap it into SP when to embed to code. Also there are cases (unfortunately) when you have no choice or have various constraints. What caused me to write all this lenghty comments is that you unconditionally marked using SPs as evil. I strongly beleive: not necessarily.

Comment: SPs are good when you don't have to maintain application you are writing using SPs, when your application WILL NOT be distributed and reside on multiple boxes. In other cases SPs are evil.

Comment: @xelibrion - your statements are silly...there are times when SPs make sense. Re: in memory testing...that is not doing any kind of real testing...there are many issues that come up based on the ORM provider.

Comment: @B Z Do you guys write unit tests at all? How many big systems like Google, Facebook, Twitter use stored procedures?

Comment: @xelibrion - yep, we do. We also write Integration Tests...none of those companies you mention probably even use an RDBMS...and, you can't compare what they do, with what the average developer works on :)

Comment: Facebook didn't use SPs when they were using MySQL http://www.flickr.com/photos/areitz/5142295170/, http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/11/9/facebook-uses-non-stored-procedures-to-update-social-graphs.html, and the fact that didn't do it helped them to switch from RDBMS quite easily. I don't want to tie myself down to RDBMS by putting logic to SPs and therefore I can change my data storage to NoSQL, blob storage in the cloud or even file system without difficulties.

Comment: @xelibrion, to state the obvious, you can't migrate from SQL server to blob or file system 'without difficulties'. And FB and Twitter aren't the only applications in the world. Any mid-sized business has in possession much more complex software (though not as scalable). And many of that apps use SPs. Also many of these apps do not migrate to another RDBMS during lifecycle (no such need). If you do not see use for highly-optimized for a particular RDBMS (or even a particular version of a RDBMS) SQL scripts or do not see why it's better to embed these scripts into a DB, well, OK. Others do.

Comment: I wouldn't say if I couldn't. With DDD, CQRS and event sourcing I can do it really easily http://cqrsinfo.com/documents/events-as-storage-mechanism/

Comment: @xelibrion, you forget that RDBMS provides extremely efficient (both cost- and performace-wise) and easy-to use tool to query data. Without RDBMS you'll have to reinvent the bicycle. Also, one should examine requirement and contraints closely before deciding on what's good or bad in a particular case. A web-site serving millions of customers has one set requirements and constraints and an internal portal for a company with 'original' requirements has a completely another one. For instance, under budget and time constraints it's often easier to create an indexed view or an SP when ORM fails.

Comment: @xelibrion, stackoverlow is an QA site, not a discussion site. The fact we both forgot. :) If you want to continue on, I suggest you to write a blog enty and post a link here.

Comment: In the most cases ORM fails if you don't know how to use it properly. I agree that architecture depends on requirements, but today RDBMS' are most effective only in one area - it is reporting. Some NoSQL solutions (such as MongoDB and RavenDB) provide much more set of capabilities from cost, performance and feature-set perspective. RDBMS' are only one side of CAP theorem (http://blog.nahurst.com/visual-guide-to-nosql-systems) and modern world has tendency to sacrifice consistency for partition tolerance

Comment: Okay, let's finish this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I would try capturing the Row not Found exception and triggering a retry of the whole operation.  Requery your Views Row and update it and call submit changes again.  Make sure you use a counter to ensure you only retry the operation five times or so, so that you are not caught in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest that you look look at using a stored procedure as @Dmitry suggested and wrap your increment and select up into one operation. That will give you two benefits: 1) It will eliminate your contention issue and 2) it will put the entire operation into one call to the database. Here's the basic idea:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spIdeasRetrieveAndLog
    @IdeaPK int
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Ideas SET Views = Views + 1 WHERE IdeaPK = @IdeaPK
    GO
    SELECT * FROM Ideas WHERE IdeaPK = @IdeaPK
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use one of messaging frameworks (for example, [NServiceBus](http://www.nservicebus.com/), but there are other options - MassTransit, Rhino Service Bus). They will help you to solve this problem in very simple and elegant way.

Comment: So, would we setup a service bus (like NServiceBus) with numberofworkerthreads=1 so that it processes the commands in order -- ensuring all commands get executed in consecutive order?

Comment: Exactly. Another option is to use multiple worker threads with some finite retries count.